# Как определить принадлежность точки к некому множеству(функции)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, матрицы

[функция, график](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP29481gide42d08cf70b400001d70fi59ic0g6da7?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=58&w=200.&h=202.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips)

Функция={y>-6, y<-|x|+5} (система неравенств)

Задание (написать программу): у пользователя запрашиваются координаты различных точек, введённые пользователем данные записываются в двумерный массив, потом эти данные (координаты точек)выводятся на экран с пометками принадлежит или НЕ принадлежит множеству.

Comment: А в чём проблема? У вас есть точка, вы проверяете, выполняются ли условия `y > -6` и `y < |x| + 5`.

(Кстати, это не уравнения, это неравенства.)

Comment: Да, неравенства, не усмотрел. Без массива легко, а в задаче нужно использовать именно матрицу!

Comment: Всё, решил. Тему можно закрыть.